# Perl: Select Filepath for csv file inside folder

Tags: perl, csv, filepath

I have a Perl Script which does some data manipulation with a selected CSV file. In the past, I have renamed the CSV file to match the one specified inside my script.

I now want to change it so that the sole file in a folder is selected, but the csv file is not always named the same. There will only ever be a single file in the folder.

I currently use this method;

```
my $filepath_in = 'C:\delete_csv_files\files_new\input.csv';
my $filepath_out = 'C:\delete_csv_files\files_processed\output.csv';

open my $in,  '<:encoding(utf8)', $filepath_in or die;
open my $out, '>:encoding(utf8)', $filepath_out or die;
```

I also want the file to retain its original name after its been processed.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: Thanks! how can I extract the filename from the path and use this as the name that it is saved as after manipulation?

Comment: @toolic, Don't use glob in scalar context like that! Use `my ($filepath_in) = glob 'C:\delete_csv_files\files_new\*';`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by toolic and commented by ikegami, you can use `glob`.

```
my ($filepath_in) = glob 'C:\delete_csv_files\files_new\*';
```

Then you can use a regex to generate the name of the output file, like :

```
(my $filepath_out = $filepath_in) =~  s!\\files_new\\!\\files_processed\\!;
```

This will give you a file with the same name, in directory `files_processed`.

If you want to force the name of the ouput file to `output.csv` like in your code snippet, then use this regex instead :

```
(my $filepath_out = $filepath_in) =~  s!\\files_new\\.*$!\\files_processed\\output.csv!;
```